# Fastapi, sqlmodel many to many with extra data

Tags: fastapi, pydantic, sqlmodel

I've done so far-

models.py

```
class UserBase(BaseSQLModel):
    first_name: str
    last_name: str
    email: EmailStr = Field(
        nullable=True, index=True, sa_column_kwargs={"unique": True}
    )
    is_active: bool = Field(default=True)
    is_superuser: bool = Field(default=False)
    status: bool = Field(default=False)
    role_id: UUID | None = Field(default=None, foreign_key="role.id")


class User(BaseModel, UserBase, table=True):
    hashed_password: str | None = Field(nullable=False, index=True)
    role: Optional["Role"] = Relationship(
        back_populates="users", sa_relationship_kwargs={"lazy": "joined"}
    )
    enterprises: list["Enterprise"] = Relationship(
        back_populates="users",
        link_model=UserEnterpriseLink,
        sa_relationship_kwargs={"lazy": "selectin"},
    )


class EnterpriseBase(BaseSQLModel):
    name: str
    description: str | None = Field(default=None, title='Description')


class Enterprise(BaseModel, EnterpriseBase, table=True):
    users: list["User"] = Relationship(
        back_populates="enterprises",
        link_model=UserEnterpriseLink,
        sa_relationship_kwargs={"lazy": "selectin"},
    )

class UserEnterpriseLink(BaseModel, table=True):
    enterprise_id: Optional[UUID] = Field(
        default=None, foreign_key="enterprise.id", primary_key=True
    )
    user_id: Optional[UUID] = Field(
        default=None, foreign_key="user.id", primary_key=True
    )
```

api.py

```
@router.post("", status_code=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
async def create_user(
        new_user: UserCreate = Depends(user_deps.user_exists),
) -> UserRead:
    user = await crud.user.create_user(obj_in=new_user)
    return user
```

user_crud.py

```
     async def create_user(
        self, *, obj_in: UserCreate, db_session: AsyncSession | None = None
) -> User:
    db_session = db_session or super().get_db().session
    db_obj = User.from_orm(obj_in)
    db_obj.hashed_password = get_password_hash(obj_in.password)
    enterprises_list = await db_session.execute(
        select(Enterprise).where(Enterprise.id.in_(obj_in.enterprises))
    )
    enterprises = [enterprise[0] for enterprise in enterprises_list]
    user.enterprises.extend(enterprises)
    db_session.add(db_obj)
    await db_session.commit()
    await db_session.refresh(db_obj)
    return db_obj
```

schema.py

```
class UserCreate(UserBase):
    password: str | None
    enterprises: list['EnterpriseBasic'] | None = None
    hotels: list['HotelBasic'] | None = None

    class Config:
        hashed_password = None
```

Now I've payload like below. How can I save extra data to database from the payload using upper models, schema and crud

```
{
    "firstName": "string",
    "lastName": "string",
    "email": "user1@example.com",
    "isActive": true,
    "isSuperuser": false,
    "status": false,
    "roleId": "ff36d9f0-1ace-43ed-b164-d941f5312568",
    "password": "string",
    "phone": "67213128",
    "enterprises": ["419bd58a-ec64-4807-b227-9dadff3c405c"],
    "classes": [
        {
            "id": "419bd58a-ec64-4807-b227-9dadff3c4051",
            "paid": true
        },
        {
            "id": "519bd58a-ec64-4807-b227-9dadff3c4051",
            "paid": false
        }
    ]
}
```